# Jquery Tabs not work on mobile browsers

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, jquery-tabs

Jquery Tabs not work on mobile browser(IPhone, Samsung browser etc.).I check on safari working fine but not working properly on IPhone Safari browser.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Features</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Q2f4m/

Problem is not in browsers, problem is in **`$(function () {`**, it should not be used with jQuery Mobile because it can cause this problems. Read more about it **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

You will need to use proper jQuery Mobile page event to initialize the tab.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $("#tabs").tabs();      
});
```